# How to open another file with the same name from another directory?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a multilingual website , so what I'm doing is creating two directories:

```
en=english                        
fr=french
```

So I'm duplicating the files I've coded. what i want to do is to write a simple code when user changes the language is to go to the other directory with the same file name, for example 
I am at `www.website.com/en/profile.php`, when user changes language he will be directed to `www.website.com/fr/profile.php`.

If you can see the only difference is the parent directory of the file, I want do this in PHP or javascript.

Comment: Might I suggest a localization file instead? All text will reside in files where templating HTML can call upon.

Comment: localization won't work , the place iam in users half of them uses english and the other half are using the other language , so i need to do it so that when i ad the link anywhere for publicity the user can pick his preferred language.

Comment: That's _Exactly_ what localization means. Terms like [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) come to mind now... You basically put all your displayed text in a language-specific file, and load the right file depending on a language parameter in the url, instead of duplicating the whole site for each language.

Comment: I would only recommend a subdomain or folder, such as `en.website.com` or `website.com/en` in they provide different communities. If the website doesn't do that, I'd just have an ini (or whatever format) with all the texts and then have PHP load that ini file. I personally don't let PHP template my HTML, I'd use smarty or [any available engines](https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+templating+engine).

Comment: that's sounds good , but what i mean if the user is at specific language and suddenly he wanted to check it in french ,  i need in two directories for SEO solutions where every content must have a unique URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`switch.php`

```
<?php
    $path = basename($_GET['path']);
    $newpath = "fr/".$path;
    header("Loaction: $newpath");
    exit();
?>
```